Singularity Container not finding files after transformation from docker
I have a docker image like this
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.6.3-runtime-ubuntu20.04
#Set environment variables to avoid some warnings during apt-get install
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
#Install necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip \
    python3-dev \
    software-properties-common \
    curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#Add deadsnakes PPA and install Python 3.11 (stable for Ubuntu 20.04)
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3.11 \
    python3.11-dev \
    python3.11-venv \
    python3.11-distutils && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#Install pip for Python 3.12
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && \
    python3.11 get-pip.py && \
    rm get-pip.py
#Ensure that `python3` points to Python 3.12
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.11 1
#Set working directory
WORKDIR /Python_Development
#Copy the requirements file and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN python3.11 -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 #Map drive
VOLUME ["/mnt/data"]
 #Copy the application files into the container

COPY DLApplication/ ./DLApplication

CMD ["python3", "DLApplication/DLEntryPointSegmentation.py"]

I copy some cuda image from nvidia, install python, my requirements and then include the directory i need. Inside this directory, there is th e DLEntrypointSegmentation.py
This script i need to start.
When i create this image and run it like this

docker run -v F:/mnt/data:/mnt/data -e CONFIG_JSON="JSON GOES HERE WITH ESCAPED " " segmentation:latest

I bind a drive, and provide a JSON to the mentioned script.
The container starts and works as intended.
I then need to convert this docker image to a singularity image.
I save the docker image with

docker save -o segmentationV3.tar segmentation:latest
Then I transform it into a singularity image with
singularity build /path/segmentationV3.sif docker-archive:///path/segmentationV2.tar

this works, however each time I try to run the singularity image, it appears to not find the >DLEntrypointSegmentation.py
I have observed, that after running it with

singularity exec /path/segmentationV3.sif ls

, the running image still thinks its inside the location where I ran the command in cmd, however the DLEntrypointSegmentation.py
should be inside the image.
the path should look something like

/path/IMAGE/DLApplication/DLEntrypointSegmentation.py

, but it is like

/path/ -> i ran the cmd here

Can someone tell me where my error lies/where to fix it?
I`m new to singularity and struggle a bit with finding it
Thanks
